# Renaming files vs pull request squash merge

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

From what I've learned, git can handle file renames/moves when you commit the rename/move in one commit and do modifications in another commit.

But how do that work when you squash merge your PR branch?

i.e.

1. In your feature branch: Rename files and commit
2. In your feature branch: Modify the files and commit
3. Create PR
4. Squash merge it into master

In the mean time someone else have modified the same files in their own feature branch.

What happens when they merge master into their feature branch? From what I understand, the rename and file modification is in the same commit in the master (due to the squash merge), right? So how will git treat that?

Answer (score 2):

> From what I've learned, git can handle file renames/moves when you commit the rename/move in one commit and do modifications in another commit.

Well, yes, but also no.

The key here is that Git does not store *changes*.  Git stores *snapshots*.  In other words, *each* commit has a *full and complete copy* of your source code.  If you rename a bunch of  files, making no other changes, and make a new snapshot, the old snapshot has the contents under the old names, and the new snapshot has the *same* contents, but under a new set of *names*.

If you rename *and modify* files, the old snapshot has the old contents under the old names, and the new snapshot has the new contents under the new names.

What Git does with `git log --follow` and `git diff --find-renames` is to take two snapshots—let's say "before" and "after" an interesting event, with the interesting event in this case being the rename—and *compare* them.  Internally, committed files are stored as <name, hash-ID> pairs (or more precisely, <mode, name, hash-ID> triples):

```
$ git ls-tree -r HEAD
[snippage]
100644 blob 41b718c29e1b9fc2981d7d14a3d25e69c31a3030    version.c
100644 blob 7c62e80577154d79bec050424945eb500d262a0f    version.h
100644 blob 069ee94a4d79422ea659a7ebe3923662f0626afa    versioncmp.c
100644 blob bb010f7a2b3c1090bc9c62f613cede7bbda86e97    walker.c
[snippage]
```

The `blob` here is in effect a text representation of part of the `mode` (`100644` is always a blob object), so each of these lines is the result of reading a *tree* entry, which holds this name-and-hash-ID pairing.

The hash ID of each file's content is based solely on the file data, not on the file's *name*.  For instance, whether the file were named `walker.c` or `funny.name`, as long as the *content* is the same, the *hash ID* will be the same too.

So, given a left and right side snapshot—before and after—if the *hash IDs* match, the *contents* match too.  This makes it very fast for `git diff --find-renames` to *find* the renames: we just line up all the matching hash IDs, and the names that are on the left got renamed to the names that are on the right.

If the files were slightly *modified*, this fast-rename-detect trick doesn't work.  Now Git has to actually extract all the left-side files, and all the right side files, and *compare* them.  Unlike the quick "look at hash IDs" trick, this is actually very hard (it's O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the number of files to be paired up).  Git will first do its best to pair up all left and right side files that it can without inspecting their contents, so that the list of "maybe renamed" files is as small as possible, and then only look at those files that aren't already paired-up.

So, Git *can* handle both situations—as long as the contents haven't changed *too* much, so that the similarity detector can burn a lot of CPU time to match up the files by similarity index—but it takes a lot less compute power to do the matching-up rename-finding if the event across which `git diff` is diff-ing two commits is *just* a rename event.  That means all the hash IDs do match up, and the fast-match code does the whole job.

> But how do that work when you squash merge your PR branch?

It doesn't.

Squash merges are *tools*.  Use them when they're appropriate.  Use some other tool when squash merges aren't appropriate.

(Remember, squash-merge means *run `git merge`, but then commit the result as an ordinary commit* rather than as a merge commit.  From the command line, `git merge --squash` acts as though you also included the `--no-commit` option, every time, so you have to run the `git commit` command yourself.  The GitHub clicky "squash and merge" button doesn't use the command line commands, so it's a bit different, but the final set of commits you get is the same as if you'd done all this on the command line.)